# How exclude powershell script file from self deletion if it deletes by file content

Tags: powershell

i need to delete several generated files. I created a script:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select-String "Generated by Terragrunt" -List | Select-Object Path | Remove-Item
```

The problem is of course it is matching the script it self, thus it deletes it self.

What is the easiest way to prevent it. I would like to have a method that is stable against changing script name and folder (it should always delete relative to its position but not it self).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the name of the current script file like this:

```
$currentScriptFile = if ($PSCommandPath) { Split-Path $PSCommandPath -Leaf } else { Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Leaf }
```

Then use as

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Exclude $currentScriptFile
```

Comment: thanks, "$PSCommandPath" is what am i looking for. i just added it this way:
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select-String "Generated by Terragrunt" -List -Exclude $PSCommandPath | Select-Object Path | Remove-Item (exclude seems to work with select?)

Comment: @dermoritz Well if you say it works for you, fine (I didn't try it like that). For me, the easiest way seems to exclude the powershell script file itself from even being enumerated before piping the rest of the files to Select-String. With Get-ChildItem, the `-Exclude` switch only works on the file Name, not the full path AND it only works if you also specify `-Recurse` (or have the path end with `\*`)